# get nested tag value from xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

i have an xml file in a special format how can i get specific tag value out of it for example if i want to get rotation value of each dict tag. as you can see that rotation value of each dict is nested in array tag that is nested in dist tag.please point me in right direction

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pu version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>C0AC8773-CEE6-4A12-9C69-320A1BDB7255</string>
    <key>Items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>90</real>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>180</real>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>270</real>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</pu>
```

this is what i tried so far

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($path);
$array = $dom->getElementsByTagName('array');
foreach($array as $key)
{
   print_r($key);
}
```

this will print all tags inside array tags but i want only rotation value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste those XML data on a file say `yourxmlfile.xml` and use `simplexml_load_file()` to parse your XML data. Using a `foreach` you can cycle through like this.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('yourxmlfile.xml');
foreach ($xml->dict->array->dict as $tag)
{
    if($tag[0]->key[3]=="rotation")
    {
        echo $tag[0]->real[2]."<br>";
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
90
180
270
```

Comment: Thats right and the xml is oddly formatted for the given task. you would think hey would have something like `<rotation>VALUE</rotation>` instead of having the value be the next sibling.

Comment: @Victory, Exactly, they don't have like _attribute_ structure , so possible way would be something this.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer, the `key`/`(value)` "pairing" is odd. However, you can use xPath for this as well:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath("dict/array/dict/key[text()='rotation']/following-sibling::real");

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'dict/array/dict/rotation: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

http://codepad.org/ib4NiBBz

Which gives:

```
dict/array/dict/rotation: 90
dict/array/dict/rotation: 180
dict/array/dict/rotation: 270
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish it with an XPath expression:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[text()='rotation']/following-sibling::real/text()");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

The XPath expression means: Find all `<real>` tags followed by any tag with the node value `rotation` and get their node value. An XPath expression allows you to have more control over the markup. You can adjust the expression as you want.

Output:

```
90
180
270
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/128612)